# Echoing PHP variables returns the variable name, not the variable value

Tags: php, echo, title

I'm creating a website that stores the base code of the website in PHP functions so that I don't have to write out the base code over and over. In my index.php page I have it call one of the functions called head and pass in a couple of variables.

This is my code for the index.php page:

```
<?php
    include "base.php";
    head("Home");
?>
```

It includes the file base.php which has the function head in it.

This is the head function:

```
<?
    function head($title) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title><?="$title | BASE"?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

As you can see the head function asks for a variable called $title and that is passed in in index.php as "Home". When the page executes though instead of `Home | Base` showing up for the title, the title shows up as `<?="$title | BASE"?>`. Why is that? I need the title to show up as `Home | Base` and I don't know why it isn't showing up like that.

Comment: You want to render some html-block passing variables into it? You're doing it very wrong!

Comment: Unless you're on PHP 5.4+, **OR** have short_open_tags enabled, then `<?=` is not available and will not trigger "PHP mode".

Comment: How else should I do it if I'm doing it very wrong? And why am I being downvoted

Comment: Also, I used <?php ?> and echo and it still isn't working.

Comment: To implement it properly you need to `include()` that html block inside a function, passing array of variables

Comment: @LeoAlfred If you changed it to `<?php` tags you need to change it into `<?php echo "$title | BASE"; ?>` and not into `<?php "$title | BASE"; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `short_open_tag` enabled to use `<?= $var; ?>` syntax in previous versions of PHP (if you use version prior to PHP 5.4).

Of course you can simple use standard PHP syntax so you can change

```
<?="$title | BASE"?>
```

into

```
<?php echo "$title | BASE"; ?>
```

if you use PHP < 5.4 or cannot set `short_open_tag` enabled

Answer (score -3):

Put the $title variable in curly braces: `<?= echo "{$title} | Base"; ?>` or use the `.` to concatenate `<?= $title . " | Base"; ?>`

This will parse the variable value instead of echoing the name. Just putting the variable name in the quotes